# NHibernate Custom IProjection that Runs a Sub-Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

Say I have 2 tables as follows:

```
MainTable (
    Id int,
    Name varchar(100)
)

RelatedTable (
    Id int,
    Value int,
    MainTableId int -- foreign key
)
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between `MainTable` and `RelatedTable`, such that `RelatedTable.MainTableId` references `MainTable.Id`.

I want to make a custom [IProjection](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/IProjection.cs) to be used as follows:

```
sess.CreateCriteria<MainTable>()
    .SetProjection(
        Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add(Projections.Property("Id"))
            .Add(Projections.Property("Name"))
            .Add(new SumOfValuesProjection(/* arguments??? */))
    )
    .List();
```

That generates the following SQL:

```
select
    Id,
    Name,
    -- how to get this sub-query from IProjection?
    (select sum(Value)
    from RelatedTable
    where RelatedTable.MainTableId = MainTable.Id) as SumOfValues
from MainTable
```

This is just a small example of what I am trying to do.  In my case, there could be dozens of these sub-query columns.  They all use aggregate functions, but may not all use `sum()`.

I am looking to create a custom `IProjection` but am not quite sure where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the exact answer, but maybe more direct one. I would like to show, how to use current NHibernate features to execute similar SQL as needed.

The trick won't be in the custom `IProjection`, but in the call to already existing powerful *IProjection* implementation: `Projections.SubQuery`

```
var criteria = CreateCriteria<MainTable>("Main")
    .SetProjection(
        Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add(Projections.Property("Id"))
            .Add(Projections.Property("Name"))

            // here we go, let's profit from existing IProjection
            .Add(Projections.SubQuery(
                   DetachedCriteria
                       .For<RelatedTable>("Related")
                       .SetProjection(Projections.Sum("Value"))
                       .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("Main.Id", "Related.MainTableId")))
                   , "value")
                )
     ...
     ;
```

In case that this approach is not enough, I would suggest to observe how this functionality is implemented in current NHibernate code. *Because still - NHibernate is Open Source ...*